# How can I backup WhatsApp files to free some space?

Tags: whatsapp-messenger

I have an old 2.3 gingerbread phone and I'd like to free some memory from time to time. What's the recommended procedure to backup files from WhatsApp and free space?
(extra: Better if I wouldn't have to go again through the whole send-SMS-registrate process)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

WhatsApp automatically makes backups every day at 4 AM and stores them in the WhatsApp folder of your Android phone. This folder is either located in your device's internal memory or external microSD card.

If you have a **external** sd-card, then you can back up your WhatsApp chat history on to sd-card.

> Go to WhatsApp > Menu Button > Settings > Chat settings > Back up
>   chats.

For phones that have an **internal** memory / internal SD card (like most Samsung devices), you will need to transfer the WhatsApp folder from your phone. There are 2 possible ways for this:
1. You can use [File Explorer](https://play.google.com/store/search?q=file%20explorer&so=1&c=apps) app to do this or 
 
2. You can copy files to to your storage card in Windows. Please find details of how to do so in this [Link](http://www.androidcentral.com/android-101-copy-files-your-storage-card-windows).

This way you are freeing the device's internal memory and it is one of the recommended ways of backing up the chat as per [FAQ](http://www.whatsapp.com/faq/en/android/20902622) of WhatsApp.